# UILabel Text Out of Bounds Some Times

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I've been straggling with this for a while 
The problem is some times with Arabic font and multiple lines, the text just get out of the UILabel frame ,,, I'll add images to be more clear...
The UILabel has a sky-blue background ,, the arrows is to show you the errors and how it's should be..

[image]

[image]

Edit:

here's the code of the resizing

```
//myString contain the text I'm showing..

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myArabicFont" size:30.0];
self.myLabel.text = myString;
self.myLabel.font = font;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
CGRect rect = [myString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(265, MAXFLOAT)
                                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                             attributes:attributes
                                context:nil];
CGRect frame = self.myLabel.frame;
frame.size.height = rect.size.height;
self.myLabel.frame = frame;
```

Comment: It is impossible for us to see what's going on without code. Post some code on how you initialize your label, set the text, and resize it to fit the text.

Comment: For starters: You are using 265 as the bounding width, is your label's width actually 265? Also, the docs say that `boundingRectWithSize:` returns fractional sizes which must be rounded off. You should use `CGRectIntegral(rect)` before using any part of the resulting frame. Also, have you tried simply performing `[self.myLabel sizeToFit]`? Is the result the same in that case or is it correct?

Comment: first yes the the frame of my label is 265 in xib,, and also this work with english letters with no problems.

Comment: @Aziz long time passed. Did you find the issue fix?

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek I came across this blog https://www.tothenew.com/blog/fix-vertical-position-issue-of-custom-ios-fonts/ you can play with minLeftSideBearing and minRightSideBearing, I mange to fix font with horizontal alignment issues but not the same problem as my question, if it works let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of measuring the text's bounding rect and assigning that to the label, let the label resize itself. Use auto layout to position the label, set its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, and just stuff the text into the label.

Also, obviously, the line break mode makes a difference.

(Also, do not mix attributed strings with a label's "native" properties. My experience is that labels get rather confused when you do that. For example, set the label's `text` and `font`, but if you're going to set its `attributedText` then don't also set its `font`. I can't tell from the code you've given whether you're doing that, since you didn't provide the code that actually sets the text.)